# Keep printing too many times in console, search name mainscript

Tags: python

New to python ... I believe this is the code where the problem occurs - how do I make it print one time?

if searchChoice == "2":

```
                nameSearch=[]
                
                while True:
                        
                    searchName = input("Please input the student name you want to check (enter QUIT to exit): ")
                    
                    if searchName.lower() == "quit":
                            break
            
                    for i in range(np.size(studentNames)):
                        if bool(re.search(searchName.lower(),studentNames[i].lower())):
                            nameSearch.append(i)     # Index for the studentNumber
                     
                        if len(nameSearch) == 0:
                            print("This student's name doesn't exist in the current list. Student numbers to pick from are: \n{}".format(studentNames))
            
                        else:
                            averageGrade = computeFinalGrades(studentGrades)
                        
                        for i in range(len(nameSearch)):
                            print("This is the information entered for student {}: \n- Name: {} \n- Student Number: {} \n- List of grades: {} \n- Average grade: {}".format(searchName,studentNames[nameSearch[i]],studentID[nameSearch[i]],studentGrades[nameSearch[i]],averageGrade[nameSearch[i]]))
                            break
  
            if searchChoice == "9":
                break
```

[Image showing console output...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUOZr.png)

Comment: Fix your identation. We can't tell where `if searchChoice == "9":` is identated.

Comment: Sorry, it wont let me - but it is indentated equally above the next "if searchChoice == "9":

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a while loop, if for some reason you want a while loop
you can have a count, like this:

```
count = 1
While count >= 1:
   #code goes here
```

This will make it repeat until count is equal to 1.